# Sending files with Web socket

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I want to create a chat using web socket (django-channels). And I have a problem, when I try to upload file data about him goes into a variable text_data in receive() function. Maybe It's more problems with code, and i will be grateful for any help. Here is a code

chat_room.js:

```
const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
    'ws://'
    + window.location.host
    + '/ws/chat/'
    + roomName
    + '/'
);

chatSocket.onerror = function(event) {
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = '<h1>Chat does not exist</h1>';
};

chatSocket.onmessage = function(e){
    console.log(1)
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (data.message){
        console.log(2)
        let messange = document.createElement('li')
        messange.textContent = data.message
        document.querySelector('.chat-log-list').appendChild(messange);
    } else if(data.file){
        console.log(3)
        let message = document.createElement('li')
        let link  = document.createElement('a')
        link.textContent = data.file.filename;
        link.href = data.file.url
        link.target = '_blank'
        message.appendChild(link)
        document.querySelector('.chat-log-list').appendChild(messange);
    }
}

chatSocket.onclose = function(e){
    console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
};

document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
    }
}

document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e){
    const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
    const message = messageInputDom.value

    const fileInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-file-input');
    const file = fileInputDom.files[0]

    if (file){
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            const fileData = event.target.result;
            
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify(fileData))
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    } else if(message){
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message
        }));
    }
 
    fileInputDom.value = ''
    messageInputDom.value = '';
}
```

consumers.py:

```
import json
from .models import *
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from user_app.models import User
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["room_name"]
        try:
            self.chat_obj = PrivateChat.objects.get(id=self.room_name)
        except PrivateChat.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                self.chat_obj = GroupChat.objects.get(id=self.room_name)
            except GroupChat.DoesNotExist:
                try:
                    self.chat_obj = Channel.objects.get(id=self.room_name)
                except Channel.DoesNotExist:
                    raise Http404()

        self.room_group_name = "chat_%s" % self.room_name
        
        
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
        )

    
    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        
        if text_data:
            self.handle_text_data(text_data)
        elif bytes_data:
            self.handle.bytes_data(bytes_data)
        
    def handle_text_data(self,text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json["message"]
        self.user = self.scope['user']

        new_message = Message.objects.create(message=message, author=self.user)
        self.chat_obj.messanges.add(new_message)
        new_message.save()
        

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name, {"type": "chat_message", "message": message}
        )

    def handle_bytes_data(self,bytes_data):
        file_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['file_name']
        message = f'{file_name} received'
        self.user = self.scope['user']
        
        new_message = Message.objects.create(file=bytes_data, author=self.user)
        self.chat_obj.messanges.add(new_message)
        new_message.save()

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name, {'type': 'file_message','message': message}
        )

    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event["message"]
        file_data = event.get('file_data',None)

        if file_data:
            self.send(bytes_data=file_data)
        else:
            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": message}))
```

chat_room.html:

```
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Chat Room{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="chat-log">
        <ul class="chat-log-list">
            <li>{{ chat_obj.create_at }}</li>
            {% for m in messages %}
                <li>{{ m.message }}</li>                
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="100">
    <input type="file" id="chat-file-input"><br>
    <input type="button" id="chat-message-submit" value="Send">
    
    
    {{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/chat_room.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally I want that it can send a text or a file and they are entered into the database and displayed on the page.